# Rest Assured Framework complete JSON response matching

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I am using Rest Assured Framework for API testing(Using Java). 
At line (1),I am expecting error as there is mismatch in expected JSON response and Actual JSON response
But instead my code is executing successfully.
Can someone please tell me if I am doing anything wrong in below code?

```
     public void test123() {
            try {
                //Read the Curl Request Input file
                String json = input.readFromTextFile(
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\inputFile\\CurlDataFile.txt");
                json = json.replaceAll(" ", "");            
                RestAssured.baseURI = "My URL";
                given().
                    contentType("application/json").
                    body(json).
                when().
                    post("").
                then().
assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("testCurlOuput1.json"));  (1)
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(JsonSchemaValidationException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I choose different library i.e. jayway.restassured library and then JSON Assert library (org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert) which will comapre actual and expected response.

```
public void test123() {         
String postData = input.readFromTextFile(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\inputFile\\CurlDataFile.txt");
        RestAssured.baseURI = "MY URL";
Response r = (Response)given().contentType("application/json").body(postData).when().post("");
            String responseBody = r.getBody().asString();           
            String curlResponse = //I am providing expected Curl response here          
       //JSON Assertion for matching Expected and Actual response
            JSONAssert.assertEquals(curlResponse, responseBody, false);
        }
```

Also sometime we may want to avoid comparing particular field from JSON like some ID field which generate dynamically which we can do using JSON comparator

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly relevant to REST-assured, but I suggest you take a look at [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate), because IMO it may be exactly what you are looking for.

One of the core features of Karate is that you can perform a full **equality** match of a JSON payload in one step.

And you can easily use JSON from files, which encourages the re-use of payloads across multiple tests.

Answer (score 0):

You are catching all Exceptions. When your assertThat(..) fails, it throws an Exception. Put a breakpoint on the e.printStackTrace(); run in DEBUG mode and check that your AssertionException/Error isn't being caught.

Instead of catching exceptions, just add all Checked Exceptions to your test signature. If an exception is uncaught, it will fail the test. Alternatively, but less prefered in my opinion, resolve by putting fail(); in the catch block.

Comment: But my code is not getting error out so it is not about handling exception.

Comment: When your assertThat().. fails, that method does throw an Exception :-). Assertion failing => Exception. That is why assertion failures fail JUnit Tests.

Comment: In your case, the "matchesJsonSchemaInClassPath" throws a JsonSchemaValidationException if it doesn't match. You catch that exception instead of letting it bubble up and fail the test. (found that exception name in the GITHUB pages of RestAssured: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured)

Comment: As per your saying, I have removed generic exception with JsonSchemaValidationException but my code never reaches to exception and completed successfully whereas I am expecting that it should throw some error as Actual JSON response in not matching Expected response.(As I have tested responses with another Java library, HTTPURLClient)

Comment: Could you update the example you provided above? :) It makes discussions easier

Comment: Do not catch the exceptions at all. Remove the Try Catch and add the exceptions to your signature. You are still catching the exceptions in your tests.

Comment: public void test123() throws IOException, JsonSchemaValidationException

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) as this provides easy comparing of complete JSONs.

Just use `.extract().response().getBody().asString()` to get the string representation of the answer.

Complete example:

```
@Test
public void getReturnsExpectedDataForMailExampleCom() throws JSONException {
    String response = get("/users/mail@example.com")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .extract().response().getBody().asString();
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(
        "{\"email\":\"mail@example.com\",\"locale\":\"de-DE\"}",
        response,
        false);
}
```

**Update** The drawback is that the complete JSON is not output to stdout if the assertion fails.